# Listview only showing up in one device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have a program that takes in parameters, stores them in a table in a database, combines with calculation data from a different table in a database and then displays them in a different activity.

I built this program testing it with the Nexus 5 api 22 emulator in android studio, and it works perfectly for this device. But now when Ive tested it with a Nexus 10, nexus 6, 3.4 WQVGA all api 22 and 21, the exact same problem occurs; 
Everything in the app works perfectly, BUT the listview isnt there. There are no errors at all in logcat. These are my related layout files:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="[directory removed for question]" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Programsactivity"
            android:label="Calculation results" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The layout of the results activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.[name].[app name].Programsactivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultslistview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/item_idField"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/item_pressurefield" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/item_heightfield" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/item_velocityfield" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting a background color to your ListView and another to your rows, thats a quick way to find out if it really is all gone.  
Also, make sure the list has items in your special case, it might be a DB problem.  
`wrap_content` for the ListView looks kind of suspicious to me, try setting it to `match_parent` and test it while having a backgroundcolor.

Comment: Without changing match_parent there was no change. But changing to  match_parent AND the background colors showed the background color of the listview, empty. So I tried changing all the elements in the listview items to match_parent aswell, but no change.

I thought about database errors at first, but wouldnt that produce an error in logcat?

Comment: Is it possible that the values I created with one device are not accessible through another? That different devices use different directories for their SQL databases?

I'm using a version of mySQLitehelper.

If this is the case, how can I make sure that values I inserted into my project can be accessed by another person with a copy of my project. What if their device(their nexus 10 api 22 emulator) doesnt read the database like mine does?

Comment: Could you  elaborate on that? How did you insert the values? It might help to add that SQLiteHelper class and the code where you access it.

Comment: I inserted the values through a function in my main code where all the constants needed for calculation(these values will never change) are hard coded into a list that I iterate through and send to SQLiteHelper. I did this once by binding it to a button, doing it, and then unbinding, seemed like a good idea at the time.

IF this is the case(different devices using different database directories) I can fix it by having that function called everytime the device starts by first checking if there are any values in the database to begin with.

I will do this tomorrow, its very late where I live